# Some kind of captcha blocks the click. command

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I wanted to automate button pressing but no command works.

The commands I used:

[image: Command_1]

[image: Command_2]

What the Inspect tool shows me:

[image: idk]

The Error code I get in Visual Studio Code:

[image: wtf]

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's also the iframe location, and how it looks like.

[image: location]

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The element you are looking for, is missing. There can be 2 possibilities. 1. xpath/css selector is wrong. 2. The element is not loaded when you try to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath seems wrong. Try below xpath.

```
Button=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Enter Raffle')]")
Button.click()
```

---

Update

It seems there are two similar element on the webpage and first one style is display none;

`options 1`: use `last button element`.

```
Button=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[contains(.,'Enter Raffle')])[last()]")
Button.click()
```

`Options two`: set the attribute to `display block;` and then click()

```
Button=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Enter Raffle')]")
chrome.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", Button)
Button.click()
```

Comment: To expand and clarify this answer: the attribute "name" is specific tot he HTML structure, as noted here, you should search by text via xpath

Comment: Hi. I checked both commands, each ends with an error. File "c:\Users\Bigga\Desktop\Scripts\Scrap.tf\test.py", line 36, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'Enter Raffle')]"))).click()
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Kierak : Can you check the DOM tree if any `iframe` tag there above  `Enter Raffle` button tag?

Comment: @Kierak : Check the updated answer and let me the status?

Comment: @KunduK Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\X\Desktop\Scripts\Scrap.tf\test.py", line 36, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(chrome,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='id=GTM']")))
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @KunduK I updated the question so you could give a look at the iframe code/location

Comment: @Kierak : check updated answer and let me know.

Comment: @KunduK omg It works, IT WORKS. The first command worked. Thank you bro, I love you, saved me a lot of time.

Comment: If you would have posted that html earlier, I would have provided solution earlier. Make sure next time you will give as much information to track down the problem. Thanks.